# Is server-side PHP code visible or accessible at client-side?

Tags: php, security, web, web-applications, webserver

1. Is it possible that a PHP script stored in a server, including public methods within the PHP script, be visible, accessible or modifiable from a client browser (including but not limited to console mode within a browser)? If yes, is a hacker able to inject any code or modify the PHP script?
2. Is it possible for a hacker to pass an argument into a PHP class method (whether public/private/protected/no visibility specified) and get to see what code exists within the method, or to see what other codes exist within a PHP script?
3. Is it best to store PHP file somewhere else rather than in /www or /htdocs directory?

If any of the following above is true, what remedies can be done?

Comment: I suggest reading this pages (and sub-pages): https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php   After that you will know the correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

1. PHP is a server side language, meaning anything that it runs will be ran and rendered on your server, the only thing that is sent back to the client is the response that you give it. This means that no PHP code will be visible in the web browser nor is accessable via the console.
2. The only time anybody will be able to pass an argument into a PHP method is if you design your code so that a URL query parameter or form data is ran through a method. Even with this, they would not be able to see the actual code unless you purposefully return your code, which you'd be able to notice immediately. As a precaution its always a good idea to filter and escape any user input as to avoid SQL Injection and other types of malicious input.
3. Im sure this is up to an individual opinion but, you can store PHP files anywhere within reason. You should store publically accessable php files in your htdocs or www folders since people will need to access those, but you always have the option to use `require_once` or `require` or `include`, etc outside of your htdocs directory by prepending `../` : example `require_once("../my_file.php");` (this file won't be publically accessable but will be included when you run the publically accessable php page that requests it, this is good for when you want to include a file of functions, etc)

Edit: As GetSet mentioned, yes, misconfiguration of your server, etc can allow someone to view the code as plain text. Also, leaving the default username/password for your FTP and SSH will also be a backdoor into your server for someone to view your code. Just make sure your server is configured properly and follows strong security standards.

Comment: An improperly configured server *can* result in the php script being downloaded as opposed to rendered.

Comment: "You should store publically accessable php files in your htdocs or www folders since people will need to access those". That's not universally true. With nginx and php-fpm, for instance, there is no reason to keep any of the PHP files in any of the root directories. It is not a matter of opinion that this is a best practice.